# How do I get the next entry in an array instead of the current one?

Tags: javascript

I have a snippet of code that does this:

If it's between 0000 and 0600, it'll display "Night." If it's between 0600 and 1200, it'll display "Morning." If it's between 1200 and 1800 it shows "Afternoon" and between 1800 and 2400 "Evening."

What I want it to do, however, is to show the *next* entry in the array, not the current one. So, between 0600 and 1200 it should show "Afternoon" and not "Morning."

Here is my code for it:

```js
function startTime() {

  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var wv = today.getDay();

  var hv = 100 * h + m;

  var wv1 = new Array();
  wv1[0] = '0000,0600,Night';
  wv1[1] = '0600,1200,Morning';
  wv1[2] = '1200,1800,Afternoon';
  wv1[3] = '1800,2400,Evening';
  
  if (wv == 1) {
    wv1.forEach(function(entry) {
      var schedule = entry.split(',');
      if (hv >= schedule[0] && hv <= schedule[1]) {

        var timeofday = schedule[2];

        //Schedule
        document.getElementById('day').innerHTML = timeofday;

      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="startTime()">
  <div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="day"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: the foreach callback has `element, index, array` params; you can get the next array element using index++; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Example:_Printing_the_contents_of_an_array

Comment: @Data except I'm assuming it should wrap around (e.g. modulo?) So if your hour falls between 1800-2400 you return the 0000-0600 one?

Comment: ^^^ will fail because you're trying to index outside the array, use a ternary `var next = (index<arr.length) ? index : 0;` inside the foreach callback. btw, i would use a function as posted in the link i gave, separate concerns to make it simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a check to see if the next index is more than the length. If it is, use 0. Otherwise use the next index.

```js
function startTime() {

  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var wv = today.getDay();

  var hv = 100 * h + m;

  var wv1 = new Array();
  wv1[0] = '0000,0600,Night';
  wv1[1] = '0600,1200,Morning';
  wv1[2] = '1200,1800,Afternoon';
  wv1[3] = '1800,2400,Evening';
  
  if (wv == 1) {
    wv1.forEach(function(entry, index) {
      var schedule = entry.split(',');
      if (hv >= schedule[0] && hv <= schedule[1]) {
        var nextTime = wv1[index >= wv1.length - 1 ? 0 : ++index];
        var timeofday = nextTime.split(',')[2];

        //Schedule
        document.getElementById('day').innerHTML = timeofday;

      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="startTime()">
  <div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="day"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This seems to be the thing that's closest to what I'm looking for, thanks! However, nothing is output when I run it.

Comment: Thank you so much. After about an hour or two I was able to incorporate this into my actual code. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

I would do it slightly differently:

```js
startTime();

function startTime(){
    var hours = new Date().getHours();
    var i = Math.floor(hours/6);
    var timeofday = ['Morning','Afternoon','Evening','Night'][i];
    document.getElementById('day').innerHTML = timeofday;
}
```

```html
<div id="day"></div>
```

**Demo with every hour**

```js
function startTime(hours){
    var i = Math.floor(hours/6);
    var timeofday = ['Morning','Afternoon','Evening','Night'][i];
    return timeofday;
}

for(var h=0; h<24; h++){
    document.body.innerHTML += h +'h => '+ startTime(h) +'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your code is unnecessarily complicated. Why not use something like:

```
var today = new Date(); 
var message;
if(today.getHours() <= 6) message = "Morning"
// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the next block in your current setup, would be to simply add 600 to the current time:

```
 var hv = (600 + 100 * h + m) % 2400;
```

Of course with other setups/objects, other solutions are possible, but getting the next block can still be done this way without an extra call for the 'next' index

Answer (score 0):

To CodeOcelot's point, the way you are approaching is more complicated than necessary, but I'm going to answer this assuming you need to follow this specific model.

**Solution:** I would add the `array` parameter to access the current array in conjunction with the `index` to access the next item.

```js
  if (wv == 1) {
    wv1.forEach(function(entry, index, array) {
      var schedule = entry.split(',');
      var nextItem = array[index++].split(',');

      if (hv >= schedule[0] && hv <= schedule[1]) {
        var nextTime = wv1[index >= wv1.length ? 0 : ++index];
        var timeofday = nextItem[2];

        //Schedule
        document.getElementById('day').innerHTML = timeofday;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Hope that this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) You're right, I needed to follow this model for my actual code. I probably should have mentioned that in my post. I'm sorry I couldn't mark this as the answer! Someone else had posted a solution doing this first. Thank you for helping out, nevertheless! :)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote code like someone before hundred years (just kidding). Please be smart and short. (BTW: I like the simple if-statements from CodeOcelot).

Another more declarative approach can be this (and it is without the if-statement that makes every code more complex). This can be done since the names are redundant to the clock-numbers.

```
var names = ["Night","Morning","Afternoon","Evening"]
var index = Math.floor(new Date().getHours() * names.length / 24)
document.getElementById('day').innerHTML = names[index];
```

Comment: It can be written (with hacks) in one line - I like one liner, but I don't like hacks in business code.